# dummy IMAP server for when server has moved

Tags: imap

I'm moving the mailserver (imap).

In the last century, when everybody was using pop3, I made a script which allowed everybody to login, and fetch a message saying "Hey, update your settings".

Now, everybody are using imap, which seems a little more complicated...
Is there a simple dummy imapd server available which does that?

Or just a script (netcat?) which can collect the usernames, so I can contact the few remaining users?

Comment: Can you just not repoint the domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory the simplest of scripts will do:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '* OK [ALERT] Mail has moved, ask Leif'
echo '* BYE'
```

In practice the ALERT may or may not be displayed to the users.

Capturing login names is more complicated and perhaps not worth the trouble.